# How to do something on insert when condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, one with a list of movies, and one with a list of dates when each movie is played. The movies list has the columns `name`, `id`, `start_date` and `end_date`, while id is a unique identifier.

The shows list (the one with the dates) has `id`,`movie_id`,`date`.

Every time I `INSERT` a new show, I'd like the movies list to be updated: If the `show.date` is before the `movie.start_date`, I'd like the `start_date` to be updated to the value of the `show.date`. Same goes for the end date - obviously if the `show.date` is after the `movie.end_date`.

The following rule is what I am stuck with: (NOTE: It would only set the start date if it worked, getting the end date done should be easy once this works...)

```
CREATE RULE "movies_start_date_setter" AS ON INSERT TO "shows"
WHERE movies.id = NEW.movie_id AND movies.start_date < NEW.date
DO (UPDATE movies SET start_date = NEW.date);
```

It returns: `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "movies"`
This error doesn't give me (as a beginner) any information where I'm missing a FROM clause and why.

Now since everybody seems to think **a rule is a bad idea** (and I tend to bow the pressure) I tried a trigger, which is absolutely totally new to me.

Using a trigger **(highly recommended)** it would look something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adjust_start_date()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    UPDATE movies SET start_date = NEW.date
    WHERE id = NEW.movie_id AND start_date > NEW.date;    
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Followed by:

```
CREATE TRIGGER adjust_start_date_trigger
   AFTER INSERT
   ON shows
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE adjust_start_date();
```

This trigger may or may not work, it solves my issue but doesn't answer my original question...
Anybody else out there smarter than me (I sure hope so!)?

Comment: Why not just omit `start_date` & calculate whenever it is needed with join & `MIN(shows.date)`?

Comment: The problem with redundant data: the need to update it till eternity.

Comment: Well, that'd be a solution... Trying to learn how to deal with rules, though ;) Out of interest, though: what would be quicker when I do an insert every week or so and a select on the movies at least once a minute?

Comment: A trigger is a **much** better solution for this - especially if you are new to Postgres.

Comment: Hmm from looking at them trigger seem much more complicated, thus I started with rules but couldn't get this (apparently simple one) to work...

Comment: A simple join + min()/max() should not cause you performance issues (just use indexes when needed). *Trying to learn how to deal with rules* -- but why? Triggers are far more superior in almost every context. Rules are historical PostgreSQL only concept, you should not bother with them, unless there is no other choice.

Comment: Alright, trigger is up and running, I'd still like to know what went wrong with that rule, though, understanding your mistakes is the only way you can learn something new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `movies` is not known in `where` clause. Use:

```
create rule movies_start_date_setter as 
on insert to shows do (
    update movies 
    set start_date = new.date
    where id = new.movie_id and start_date > new.date
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The reson for the error message is that you reference table `movies` in the `WHERE` clause.

You could try with a query rewrite rule like this:

```
CREATE RULE movies_start_date_setter AS
   ON INSERT TO shows DO ALSO
   UPDATE movies
      SET start_date = LEAST(NEW.date, start_date),
          end_date = GREATEST(NEW.date, end_date)
      WHERE id = NEW.movie_id
        AND NEW.date NOT BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

but that won't work with multi-line `INSERT`s like this:

```
INSERT INTO shows (id, movie_id, date) VALUES
    (1, 42, <very small date>),
    (2, 42, <very large date>);
```

because only one of the dates in the `movies` row with `id = 42` will get changed.

Rules are tricky and hard to understand.

You are better off with a trigger.